# Flutter: How to change the icon returned by navigation?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in Flutter. I want to change the icon returned by navigation.

Screen1 Code:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => Screen2(),
  ),
);
```

Screen2 Code:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Container(),
),
```

Comment: just for confirmation... do you mean the button on the second2 to go back to screen1?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AppBar()` widget has a leading property where you can customize the navigation icon.

Here's an example:

```
      AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.menu_rounded,
            ),
         ),
      ),
```

Check this helpful documentation for Material App Bars: https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/flutter